# How to Truncate table from a .sh script?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I've got this .sh script to optimize table

```
#!/bin/sh 
mysql -u'user' -p'pwd' -D'db' </var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/optimize.sql
```

...and this sql in optimize.sql

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `this_table`
```

This all works fine.

Now I'm doing the same thing to Truncate a table:

```
#!/bin/sh 
mysql -u'user' -p'pwd' -D'db' </var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/truncate.sql
```

...and this sql in truncate.sql

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `this_table`
```

...but it doesn't work! What is wrong?

P.S. I used a Crontab to run .sh every x minutes and this works only for optimization

Comment: :-) oh no, no...this is only an example, but now i'm going to edit it...have you got an idea? Why does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a file to store the mysql credentials, e.g:

```
nano .my.cnf
```

and add the following content:

```
[mysql]
user=your_user
password=the_super_secret_password
```

Then execute your SQL statement(s) in your shell script(s) like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
`mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/.my.cnf -e "truncate table this_table;"`
```

**Why put the credentials in a separate file?** 
So that all of the shell scripts that you have that use these credentials don't have to be individually updated when the time comes to change the password.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "truncate table this_table" | mysql -u'user' -p'pwd' -D'db'
```

Comment: ok now i'm going to try...but...in your .sh script semms I can't specify my sql query...Are you sure it should work?

Comment: well, I'm just saying you can echo query instead of cat'ing query and have just one sh file insetead of two (sh+sql) files. I think it's handy. It does the same thing. And should work (if user have rights and tables exist, and mysql is in the cron %PATH%)